# Xcode 4.1 issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have installed just installed MAC OS Lion and Upgraded Xcode to 4.1. But now I can't build my projects to devices, because Xcode doesn't even see them. All worked fine in Xcode 4.02 and Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it might be just about creating a scheme. Just try to add a new scheme.